# How to fix duplicated data in angular dropdown list

Tags: angular

I have two dropdown list which have names of experts from my database.So for example I choice in first dropdown list name Jon Smith then in second dropdown you cant choice Jon Smith again because its already chosen in first dropdown. Is it even possible to do it?

```
<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="survey.expertOne" class="form-control" name="expertOne + i">
<option *ngIf="survey.expertOne && survey.expertOne.name" value="{{survey.expertOne}}" disabled selected>{{survey.expertOne.name}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let expert of survey.experts" value="{{expert._id}}">{{expert.name}}</option></select>
</td>

<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="survey.expertTwo" class="form-control" name="expertTwo + i">
<option *ngIf="survey.expertTwo && survey.expertTwo.name" value="{{survey.expertTwo}}" disabled>{{survey.expertTwo.name}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let expert of survey.experts" value="{{expert._id}}">{{expert.name}}</option></select>
</td>
```

I expect to not being able to pick same value in both dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to remove one selected element from Select One to Select Two, the best solution is that you create two variables containing the same list of experts, selectOne loops through expertsOne and selectTwo loops through expertsTwo. Then using an event listener, you delete/add the element selected/unselected, from one array or the other.

```
<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="survey.expertOne" (ngModelChange)="onExpertOneChange($event)" class="form-control" name="expertOne + i">
<option *ngIf="survey.expertOne && survey.expertOne.name" value="{{survey.expertOne}}" disabled selected>{{survey.expertOne.name}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let expert of experts1" value="{{expert._id}}">{{expert.name}}</option></select>
</td>

<td>
<select [(ngModel)]="survey.expertTwo" (ngModelChange)="onExpertTwoChange($event)" 
 class="form-control" name="expertTwo + i">
<option *ngIf="survey.expertTwo && survey.expertTwo.name" value="{{survey.expertTwo}}" disabled>{{survey.expertTwo.name}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let expert of experts2" value="{{expert._id}}">{{expert.name}}</option></select>
</td>
```

and in your component :

```
//Arrays containing the same experts initially
experts1 :Expert[]
experts2 : Expert[]
//Experts used to readd the unselected element from one to another
expert1 :Expert
expert2:Expert
onExpertOneChange($event){
//This means that the expert is being unselected, so we need to push it back to list one
if(expert1 && expert1._id==$event)
this.experts2.push(expert1);
else
{
this.expert1 = this.experts1.find(x=> x._id==$event);
this.experts2=this.experts2.filter(x=>x._id!=$event);}
}}
onExpertTwoChange($event){
//This means that the expert is being unselected, so we need to push it back to list one
if(expert2 && expert2._id==$event)
this.experts1.push(expert2);
else
{
this.expert2 = this.experts2.find(x=>{return x._id==$event);
this.experts1=this.experts1.filter(x=>x._id!=$event);}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use this style to assign dynamic value in all your options:

```
<option *ngFor="let expert of survey.experts" [value]="expert._id">{{expert.name}}</option></select>
```

and try to not use "export" keyword in both select tag, for example, use export1 and expore2

Comment: and also for the name of your select tags you must use this style: [name]=" expertOne + i "